# Testing a function that use user input in Replit unit tests

Tags: python, replit

I'm trying to write test code for a python function in Replit. The function is taking user input from the console. As written in the test need to pass a value to the function.
Test code:

```
  self.assertTrue(play(10) <6)
```

In the Function, user input needs to be taken as below(there are more codes in the function that use num and n to determine return value:

```
def play(n):

    num = int(input("Enter the ammount"))

  return num
```

I get the error:
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin

Is there a way to test functions with user inputs in the Replit unit test as the above method is not working?

Comment: Why does `play` take an argument if you ignore it?

Comment: There are more codes to add. I just added input because it is the one giving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) to patch just about anything under the sun, and that includes built-in functions.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['0', '5']):
    self.assertTrue(play(10) < 6)
```

As pointed out in the comments, your function `play` should either take an argument (and not call `input`) or should not take an argument. Right now, you take `n` but never use it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try unittest.mock.patch, but can it do both argument and user input? this is the use case I want. We give markets to this exercise so I don't want to add the whole answer here. That is why I deleted not important codes from the play function where I would use the passed parameter and user input to calculate the return value.

Comment: It worked '''with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['0', '5']):'''

Answer (score 0):

```
def play(n):
  num = int(input("Enter the ammount"))
  return num
```

Regarding above function, you need to modify it like,

```
def play(n):
  return n/2
```

Thus it becomes clean (even pure). So you can easily test it like

```
self.assertTrue(play(10) < 6)
```

Then if you want pass a user provided input to it, just

```
num = int(input("Enter the ammount"))
play(num)
```